# What's the difference in the interpretation of $y = x$ and $y(x) = x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Both $y = x$ and $y(x) = x$ describe a line, but what are some of the differences between their uses, and can they ever be used interchangeably?

Comment: In the first equation there is a natural assumption that $y$ depends on $x$, but of course, depending on the environment, it can also be seen as a plane in the 3D coordinate world. Your second equation indicates that $y$ is a function of $x$ and so there is only one input (x) and one output (y)...

Answer (score 1):

$y=x$ simply represents a line passing through origin, while $y(x)=x$ here $y$ is behaving as a function of $x$, in this case your function is identity function , you have to specify a domain and a codomain. Other possible functions are like $y(x)=x^2$ and so on for example.

Comment: $y=x$ does not have to be a line through the Origin...(See my comment above)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is just a relationship between coordinates, which might or might not be fulfilled for any given point. Given such a relationship, it is customary to illustrate it by putting black color on the points of a coordinate system where the relationship is fulfilled.

The second one says that $y$ is a function, a "rule" which for every input value $x$ gives you an output value $y(x)$. The equation tells you the exact details of the "inner workings" of this specific function. It is customary to illustrate the function by putting black color on every point in a coordinate system that are of the form $(x,y(x))$.

Answer (score -1):

The only reason y(x) = x describes a line is because, for any value of x, y(x) will be the same, as per the definition of y(x). As Kushal Bhuyan said, you can define y(x) to be any function you want. Also, when you graph y = x, there will be an x - axis and a y - axis, while if you graph y(x) = x, there will be an x - axis and a y(x) axis (or any other function that you choose).